# Model Database Normalization

Tags: sql, database, oracle, normalization, denormalization

I have the following data and i want to model it as the best database normalization.

I have a set of buildings each building contains a set of levels and each level contain a set of flats.

- Building: has number, name, height, color
- Levels: has number, name
- Flat: has number, name

I want to design a normalized database for this model.

#### Edit

The guy model it as:

#### Building

```
 Building_Number PK, Name , Height, Color
```

#### Level

```
 Level_Number PK, Building_Number FK, Name
```

#### Flat

```
 Flat_Number PK, Level_Number FK , Building_Number FK, Name
```

and so on if he had another table that reference the Flat will include the columns:

```
 Table_ID PK, Flat_Number FK, Level_Number FK , Building_Number FK, .....
```

And he said that this is the normalized design for the database and this is best for performance.

Is this is the best design? or what?

Comment: Are you asking us to do your homework for you? Why don't you tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Well, you've got everything you need, or almost : 3 tables (Building, Level, Flat), and it would probably be a good idea to add a Color table, so where's your problem ?

Comment: Good idea. Once you've done it come back, show what you've done, and make your question more specific.

Comment: take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization
Now you've got everything you need

Comment: First get your hands on theoretical concept about Database Normalization from the above link... There are many forms of Normalization exist.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply, i asked about the best design for my model according to Database Normalization.

Comment: I am working as a developer and i faced a model like that and the Database guy model it differently than the way i know .... so i asked the experts here

Answer (score 0):

very simple

**Building**

> Building_Number PK, Name , Height, Color

**Building_Level**

> Level_Number PK, Level_Name,  Building_Number FK
>   Building(Building_Number)

**Flat**

> Flat_Number PK, Name,  Level_Number FK Building_Level(Level_Number)